# "OpenCL build failed" error when rendering with GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am trying to render my Images in GPU Computer but after 1 Minute or so this message pops up:

> OpenCL build failed: errors in console.

Now whats with that? Anyone experiencing that as well?

*Working on:
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)
2.3 GHz Intel Core i7
NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB*

Comment: As the message says, did you checked the console?

Comment: BTW as far as I can see, your card is compatible with Cycles

Comment: Check that the drivers for your GPU are up to date. Try Re-installing them

Comment: What is the error message in the console?

Comment: @SebastianJaeger to access the console please read: https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/console_window.html?highlight=console

Comment: Try to render it on the cpu. It is posible that it is somthing that buggs the gpu in the scene.

Comment: I have had the same problem. I got the latest blender build (19 Jan 2017) from https://builder.blender.org/download
and I can now render using my GPU (R9 280), without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

As I just investigated in https://developer.blender.org/T48842 - if no errors was really produced (despite msg "errors in console. ") try to run blender with "--debug-memory" option - it enables "fully guarded memory allocator" which magically does things.

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia Graphic Cards don't really work with OpenCL on OSX.

You have to install [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/mac-driver-archive.html), restart Blender and chosse in the

`User Preferences --> System --> Compute Device --> GPU`

CUDA.

Then it should work.